# Cannot read image written to file

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

I am trying to write an image on storage then reading it. Write operation is successful but read fails. I have tried using `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);` when calling the responsible activity but was of no help.
This is how I write image:

```
public void savepic(Bitmap pic)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = dBcontract.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try
    {
        File image = createImageFile();
        Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "lcukerd.com.android.fileprovider", image);
        out = new FileOutputStream(image);
        pic.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
        values.put(eventDBcontract.ListofItem.columnpic, photoURI.toString());
        db.insert(eventDBcontract.ListofItem.tableName2, null, values);
        Log.i(TAG, "Pic saved " + photoURI.toString());
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally
    {
        try
        {
            if (out != null)
            {
                out.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException
{
    String EName = "Image";
    File storageDir = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(EName, ".jpg", storageDir);
    return image;
}
```

This is how I read image:

```
public Bitmap getDownloadedpics(int index)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = dBcontract.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(eventDBcontract.ListofItem.tableName2, projection2, null, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToPosition(index);
    Bitmap photo = null;
    try
    {
        Log.d(TAG,cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(eventDBcontract.ListofItem.columnpic)));
        photo = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(),
                Uri.parse(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(eventDBcontract.ListofItem.columnpic))));
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Can't read image");
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Returned " + String.valueOf(cursor.getCount()) + " pics");
    return (photo);
}
```

I get Exception at `photo =

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(),
                Uri.parse(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(eventDBcontract.ListofItem.columnpic))));
```

Exception is :

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider android.support.v4.content.FileProvider from ProcessRecord{6118b35 21772:lcukerd.com.instaswipe/u0a157} (pid=21772, uid=10157) that is not exported from uid 10101
```

I have checked other similar question but seems like they are all for some other type of problem. Help me solve it.

Comment: `Uri photoURI = FileProvid...` You are not using that uri to write something to file. You are not using FileProvider to write a file. So what you say in the subject does not come true.

Comment: @greenapps then should I write "contentResolver to write a file". I am sorry but this part of android is still a mystery to me.

Comment: You used FileOutputStream to write a bitmap to file.

Comment: @greenapps okay, then how do I solve this issue?

Comment: You should first tell why you would want to use a file provider. File providers only make sense if you want to provide a file to another app. But it looks as if your code is all in the same app.

Comment: @greenapps Oh yeah! you are right, I don't need it. I just copied this code from one of my previous apps where i needed to share with other apps. Wait, let me try normal file read-write approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of photoUri.toString() put image.getAbsolutePath() in your database.

If you want to read the file get the path from the database. Construct a File object en use FileInputStream. Then let BitmapFactory read the data from the stream.

Comment: You dont need the stream as BitmspFactory can read from file.

Comment: Yes, It worked. Can you provide me link to place where I can read all these storage related things in android like fileprovider and content resolver? right now, I try to avoid this by using alternates.